# Rails 4 form remote update div issue

Tags: ruby, forms, tags, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some problems to update my div after submitting a form with Rails 4. Here is the relevant part of my code:

**View:**

_details.html.haml

```
= form_tag(url_for(save_answer_path(format: :js)), remote: true) do
 (some html code ....)
 = submit_tag t('app.bouton.send'), id: 'sendButton'

%div#divlogs
 = render partial: 'logs'
```

**Controller:**

```
def save_answer
 some code ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**JS:**

save_answer.js.erb

```
$('#divlogs').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'logs') %>");
```

When I submit, everything is called correctly but I'am getting an incorrect output. What I want is to update my div, but instead I get a page with what I have on my JS file, but with the content of my partial.

**Example:**

My URL after submitting:

```
http://domaine/controller/save_answer.js
```

What I get on the screen:

```
$('#divlogs').html("<p>This should appear on the div </p>");
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried just `form_tag(save_answer_path, remote: true)`. It should be enough

Comment: you should also check that rails.js is used (check the page source)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I tried many things, I get an error:

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

Comment: @VladKhomich No trace of rails.js. I will do the necessary.

Comment: @VladKhomich Thanks a lot, it was that! Could you write an answer so I could validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

As @VladKhomich said in the comments above, I was missing the JS file rails.js.

You can download it from here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js